# Image appear at location of touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uitouch

I am wondering how I would go about getting an image to appear at the location of the users touch. I have a UIButton associated with an IBAction, and when the user clicks the button, I want an image to appear at the x,y of the touch.

Anyone have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: u mean in UIbutton or in the UIView touch location.?

Answer (score 0):

Why you used the UIbutton for adding an image in the touch location ?

The below code is to add an image in the touch location of a view. Try this
 (Don't forget to add delegate in .h file)

```
       - (void)viewDidLoad
{
//code for adding touch recognizer for UIview. 
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x-imagewidth/2,location.y-imageheight/2,imagewidth,imageheight)];
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but I get an exception when I run this and click on the screen, any ideas?

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage superview]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance

EDIT: No more exception, but image does not appear.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how to get this to work over a UIButton? I need an image to appear over my button.

Comment: I don't have any hands-on experience in this. I think it is not possible to add an image as a part of UIButton (other than bg or button image). 
The best way to create a custom view and add a image view to that view. And apply touch recognizer to that custom view and then use that view like button. (i.e. add it in the parent view as you add uibutton)